# Hiding div with cookies after a second visit user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

Hello friends have tried hard and not found how do I thank for the help now.

I want to hide a div with cookies after a second visit of the user that is when the User visit the page div appears later when the User leave the page and return the div does not appear.

Here my code:

```js
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if( document.activeElement && document.activeElement.tagName == 'IFRAME' ){
 jQuery.post(window.location.href, {click: 1});
 document.getElementById('mime').remove();
    }
});
 




jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){jQuery("#mime").remove();});
    document.onkeypress = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            jQuery("#mime").hide();

            return false;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            jQuery("#mime").hide();
         
            return false;
        }
    }
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
        event = (event || window.event);
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            jQuery("#mime").hide();
            
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="mime" style="position:absolute; z-index:99999999999999; opacity:0.0; filter: alpha(opacity=0) ">
<script type='text/javascript'>
habilita=true;
if(document.all){}
          else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);document.onmousemove=mouse;function mouse(e)
          {if(navigator.appName="Netscape"){xcurs=e.pageX;ycurs=e.pageY;}else{xcurs=event.clientX;ycurs=event.clientY;}
         if(habilita){ document.getElementById("mime").style.left=(xcurs-230)+"px";document.getElementById("mime").style.top=(ycurs-150)+"px";}}
</script>



</div>
```

Comment: your code has nothing to do with the question your asking.

Comment: I just need to hide div using cookies <div id="mime" style="position:absolute; z-index:99999999999999; opacity:0.0; filter: alpha(opacity=0) ">



</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Show modal only if `modalShown` value is `undefined`

```
if (!Cookies.get('modalShown')) {
  // show modal
}
```

Save to cookies when user visits a page

```
Cookies.set('modalShown', true);
```

Comment: Friend Thanks for the quick response but I am layman in programming would have to show where I put the code or maybe you can edit my code and now post the required way again for the help

Comment: I dont understand your code at all, and to be honest I dont want to. I recommend you to put some efforts and learn some javascript, then you can try to implement it yourself and only then you should ask specific questions.

Comment: Really're tricky to work for days I try.

This code it is a hidden div that follows the mouse.

Comment: I just need to hide div using cookies <div id="mime" style="position:absolute; z-index:99999999999999; opacity:0.0; filter: alpha(opacity=0) ">



</div>